# Ejecutar tarea asíncrona en DatePickerDialog estático

Tags: android, datepicker, asincronismo

Buenas colegas hoy me encuentro con un problema el cual es el siguiente, necesito ejecutar una tarea asíncrona la cual es publica en un DatePickerDialog el cual es estático por sintaxis si no me equivoco, el código es el siguiente:

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
static  class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
        year = y;
        month = m;
        day = d;

        globalVariable.calendar.set(year, m, day);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        fechaSelected = sdf.format(globalVariable.calendar.getTime());

        new getEventsAyncTask().execute(); //TAREA ASINCRONA QUE NECESITO QUE SE EJECUTE

    }
}
```

Este es el error que salta al intentar ejecutar el proyecto

```
Error:(353, 13) error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Imagen descriptiva 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El parámetro que indica el problema es el del listener:

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html

Puedes definir una variable para asignar el listener:

```
  OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
```

posteriormente crear el listener para poder instanciar el `DatePickerDialog`:

```
OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
             ...
             ...
             ...
        }
    };
```

y entonces definirlo en tu clase que extiende de `DialogFragment` :

```
 @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, ondateSet, year, month, day);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a aplicar tu respuesta, aun que sobre lo que he investigado es que como mi método asíncrono es publico no se puede ejecutar en el DatePicker porque este es statico, anexo una imagen